# STM32 L073RZ incorrect watchdog (IWDG) timing

Tags: arm, embedded, stm32, nucleo

From the datasheet, it is clear that the clock to watchdog is 37Khz. The equation for calculating the reload counter value is.

```
counter = LSI * timeout / prescalar
```

I choose timeout as 25sec and prescalar as 256. so the counter value is 3613.

The code written for testing the same is given below. So I expect system reset if watchdog is not reloaded within 25sec.

```
while(1)
{
      HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LD2_GPIO_Port, LD2_Pin);
      HAL_Delay(24000);
      HAL_IWDG_Refresh(&hiwdg);
}
```

But for the above code, the system is resetting even if i reloaded the watchdog within 25sec.

IWDG_init is given below.

```
static void MX_IWDG_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN IWDG_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END IWDG_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN IWDG_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END IWDG_Init 1 */
  hiwdg.Instance = IWDG;
  hiwdg.Init.Prescaler = IWDG_PRESCALER_256;
  hiwdg.Init.Window = 4095;
  hiwdg.Init.Reload = 3613;
  if (HAL_IWDG_Init(&hiwdg) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN IWDG_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END IWDG_Init 2 */

}
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You should show us the code that initialises the watchdog. If you make your `HAL_Delay()` shorter, does that fix it? i.e. is the problem that `HAL_IWDG_Refresh()` doesn't seem to work at all, or that you're not refreshing the watchdog quickly enough?

Comment: Yeah, when I reduce the delay 23000ms, it fixes and system not resetting.

Answer (score 4):

The watchdog is clocked by the LSI oscillator, which is optimized for low power consumption, not accuracy.

The datasheet I have (revision 7) says that the LSI frequency could be anything from 26 to 56kHz.

You have to assume the maximum clock when calculating your delay.

Also remember that whatever clocks your system clock is not perfect, and then add some tolerance for software jitter too.

Comment: when I calculate the counter with 40khz frequency for 25sec timeout, It works as expected. I this the reason for it?

Comment: Because the frequency IS NOT 37kHz, it is closer to 40kHz.

Comment: Then How do I do the calculations which independent of boards?

Comment: You have to assume the maximum clock (56kHz) when calculating your delay, and then add more for the inaccuracy of your system clock, and then add more for the software jitter.

Comment: @vishnumc You would normally reset the watchdog much faster than the timeout period.  I would suggest that if the watchdog is _nominally_ 26 seconds you should aim to reset it within say 2.6 seconds.  Typically every iteration of your application's executive loop (somewhat more complex if you are using an RTOS and multiple threads).  In a real-time system, such a loop should be very short, and deterministic (take constant or bounded time), with no blocking - specifically no HAL_Delay.  The point is the IWDG should not need precision because the reset rate should be much faster.